# Java - Unable to create a file on a shared folder with full write access

Tags: java, file, creation, java-service-wrapper

Hi I have a java application which creates an xml file on a remote shared folder. If I run through eclipse it creates the xml file without any problem. But if i create a jar and try to run the same, it throws exception message "Access is denied" . I can manually create a file on that shared folder and both are on same network running windows xp. I am not sure if anybody has noticed this problem. Please provide your suggestions. I am using Java 6 SDK with eclipse 3.5. By the way below are the vm arguments that i am using

```
-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  
-Djava.security.policy=C:\server.policy
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///C:/config/log4j.xml
```

My server policy file

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Comment: Show exact command line that fails.

Comment: Please remove the commandline parameter with the security policy and retry.

Comment: This application is run as a java service using JSW. below are the additional parameters i am using part of conf file.                            <br># Additional VM debug parameter settings
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true 
wrapper.java.additional.5=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
wrapper.java.additional.6=-XX:OnError="log_error JVM %p"
wrapper.java.additional.7=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///C:/config/log4j.xml
wrapper.java.additional.8=-Djava.security.policy=C:\server.policy

Comment: Removed the security policy, still not much help. But I don't know how  it is working in Eclipse and not working when I run it as part of java service wrapper. Do you suggest me to check any settings on the JSW config file?

Comment: Does it work if you run the JAR without the service wrapper (i.e. double-click or command line outside eclipse)?

Comment: If you are using JWS then perhaps the code is not executed with the the login user's privileges but with the administrator privileges or even some other technical user's privileges. Have you checked that?

Comment: @ A.H you hit the nail. Login previlege was the problem.I added "Logon" as administrator for the service in services menu and it worked. Thank you so much. I was struggling from past 2 hours to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up the comments:

If you are using JWS then perhaps the code is not executed with the the login user's privileges but with administrator privileges or even some other technical user's privileges.

Comment: Agreed :). The service's login account should be the first place to look at.

Comment: @Learner, by default if you run as windows service it's the local SYSTEM user account. You can also use the JSW to set the user by using wrapper.ntservice.account properties (note you need to reinstall the service first)

Comment: @Naytzyrhc, Thank you for the updated info. I will check that option as well.